# Neo4j HA Replication tx_push_factor

Tags: neo4j

I'm having a problem with Neo4j. I have 3 machines and need the three servers are always consistent. The problem is that at some point the slave does not have the update of the master. The update period can take up to several minutes (odd).

What differs from the standard in my configuration is:

```
ha.tx_push_factor = 2
ha.com_chunk_size = 10M
```

Does anyone know if you can upgrade the three servers at the same time? How to ensure database consistency? I'm using version 2.2.1.

All help is welcome.

thank you

Comment: The push is optimistic. Doesn't necessarily guarantee 100% consistency. What's your pull_interval set to?

Comment: Michal, I doesn't change pull_interval default value. In neo4j manual, the value is 0s.

Comment: which means never if I remember correctly. Could you try 10?